# 80s sci-fi horror movie. Scientists in an underground 'dimensional research' facility accidentally bring something nasty back

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I was a wee lad when I saw it 30 years ago.  This is what I can remember.  The film is focused on an underground research center where they travel to other dimensions.  Something comes back with them on one trip and people start getting killed off.  I can't remember much else, except that it also involved at least one woman in a stasis/cryo chamber and in the end, the monster kills a scientist lady with a pipe through the gut and says something like, he'll take this one back, just before going to its dimension.

The protagonist and the cryo lady are then left in the research facility and the movie ends.

Comment: And is it the 'monster' that says `"he'll take this one back"`? Or was it someone else? Like, could the 'monster' speak?

Comment: Stranger Things!

Comment: @Chloe - you could relate Stranger Things to a multiple movies, books and games which it rips mercilessly in the name of homage. First series it was kind of new and fun to spot the links beyond Stephen King. Now I think it's lazy writing, bordering plagiarism - common in screenwriters who rake over historical writers like John Wyndham, Asimov and Clarke and rehash them for a modern audience. X files did this previously.

Comment: @Applefanboy What do you think of Rick & Morty?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found it.  Shadowzone, from 1990.  I kept looking for 80s movies but was just short, lol.  It did have an underground lab and alternate dimensions, but it wasn't hibernation or cryogenics but experiments in deep sleep conciousness that caused the rifts.

Comment: Cool. I remember seeing this when I was a wee lad too. (not at all an appropriate movie for that age though...) Feel free to accept your own answer by clicking the checkbox. This will help other people who might have the same question.

Comment: It wont let me for 2 days, lol.

On a tangent, this is a good text synopsis breakdown of the whole movie:

http://www.bmoviegraveyard.com/reviews/S/Shadowzone/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowzone_(film) It seems your stasis lady is on the DVD cover.

Comment: That realization that 1990 was "about 30 years ago"...

Answer (score 9):

Could this be [Xtro II: The Second Encounter](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100975/)?

> *Military scientists discover an alternate dimension and, subsequently,
>   aliens with an appetite for human flesh.*

Comment: Pretty close.  It was like 30 years ago that I saw the movie, so its possible I am mis-remembering some things or mixing some movies together.

I'll put this on the maybe pile for now, still looking around myself.